# Understanding CLOS :after and primary methods

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, clos, generic-function, method-combination

In the hunchentoot source code, there is an `:after` defmethod called [initalize-instance](https://github.com/edicl/hunchentoot/blob/5cb8ed163dc638f497d0818d006e4938da0169ed/session.lisp#L152).

This particular example is one of a handful of `:after` methods called `initalize-instance` throughtout the project.

My experience with CLOS taught me that a primary method is required for `:before`, `:after` and `:around` methods can be used.

But in the hunchentoot package, I cannot see how they have created the primary methods to allow the `:after` methods to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol `initalize-instance` is in the `COMMON-LISP` package. It is one of the generic functions provided by the standard. If you check this generic function, you'll find that it has many methods. There is also a matching primary method. Methods can be declared anywhere, they don't need to be in a particular file.

```
CL-USER 9 > (defclass my-class () (a b))
#<STANDARD-CLASS MY-CLASS 8010021793>

CL-USER 10 > (defmethod initialize-instance :after ((instance my-class)
                                                    &rest initargs &key)
               (print `(:aftermethod for initialize-instance
                        of class my-class
                        and instance ,instance)))
#<STANDARD-METHOD INITIALIZE-INSTANCE (:AFTER) (MY-CLASS) 8010027193>

CL-USER 11 > (make-instance 'my-class)

(:AFTERMETHOD FOR INITIALIZE-INSTANCE OF CLASS
 MY-CLASS AND INSTANCE #<MY-CLASS 80103A979B>) 
#<MY-CLASS 80103A979B>
```

The method combination for `initialize-instance` with an object of class `my-class` looks like this:

```
MULTIPLE-VALUE-PROG1
 CALL-METHOD
  (METHOD INITIALIZE-INSTANCE (STANDARD-OBJECT))
 CALL-METHOD
  (METHOD INITIALIZE-INSTANCE :AFTER (MY-CLASS))
```

The primary method for `STANDARD-OBJECT` is system provided.

```
CL-USER 12 > (typep * 'standard-object)
T
```

Above shows that the instance is also of class `standard-object`, because `standard-object` is a superclass of `my-class`.

```
CL-USER 13 > (class-direct-superclasses (find-class 'my-class))
(#<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-OBJECT 80D01BCA7B>)
```

The class `standard-object` is a superclass of the class `my-class`.

Comment: interesting... okay i got it. A follow up question. How are args passed into `:after` methods? where does `initargs` come from?

Comment: @vinn they are the same args with which the generic function is called.

Comment: @vinn see the documentation: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_init_i.htm#initialize-instance